# How can I set a 3rd party cookie in a script served from remote domain?

Tags: javascript, cookies

It may be easy, but I never worked with cookies and the issue confuses me a little.

So let's say I have a script. It is uploaded to remote CDN.
I am using it by getting it in

```
<script src=http://link-to-script.com/script.js></script>.
```

Then, I load html code with those  tags and run in on localhost so it gets the script from CDN.
Now, I use some of the script's function that sets a cookie within it with ***document.cookie***. In this part I would like to have the cookie not be set on a localhost domain(which is a case right now), but on a domain that the script was served from(CDN). I want to have 3rd party cookie instead of 1st party.

What is the best possible way to do that? Could you please point me to right direction?

Comment: You can't set a cookie on another domain, that is a security risk.

Comment: You can’t have third party cookies. It is not permitted by the browser.

Comment: Once a script is loaded, it runs in the context of the containing page. The location that the script came from is not relevant, and it can't set cookies in that domain.

Comment: The real only way is if the CDN has an API that you can send information to and then the CDN can set the cookie, but `localhost` cannot set the cookie on the CDN remotely.

Comment: I know, but it is a domain that I am serving script from, so I thought it gives me some control over that? I don't want to set a cookie on someone's domain that I have no power of.

Comment: *I don't want to set a cookie on someone's domain that I have no power of*  --  Then your only option is to **download** the script instead of serving it remotely ..  Regardless of what you *don't want* -- This is the way browsers handle JS.  No cross domain cookies, sessions or even control over content within iFrames ..  It's all bad juju that can be used for malicious intent (not saying that *you* are intending nefariousness) --  Just that the world is safer because of these sorts of policies.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can refer [Can a 3rd party js script write cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747379/can-a-3rd-party-js-script-write-cookies)

To write third-party cookies (i.e. where the cookie is on the domain of the third party) requires that the **cookies be sent in the headers of a download from that third party**, and not written by JS code.

Write below code in request headers, MDN reference link  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie

```
Set-Cookie: <cookie-name>=<cookie-value>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only set cookie for **current domain** and it's **sub-domains**.

***For-Example:***

You can create cookie for `a.mydomain.com` , `b.mydomain.com`, `c.mydomain.com` from `mydomain.com`.

You **can't** create cookie for `mydomain.com` from `anotherdomain.com`.

---

**Cross-Domain Cookies**

But if you want to create cookie for another domain, You need to **redirect to that particular URL** and create cookie from that site.

**OR**

If you want to create cookie for another domain, you can try this,

```
<img src='http://www.anotherdomain.com/createCookie.php'>
```