# set G_ENABLED_IDPS (google auth) cookie to secure

Tags: javascript, cookies

I need to change a cookie to be marked as 'secure'
It is called `G_ENABLED_IDPS` and it helps authenticate users. we only use the cookie when customers want to make a referral from their gmail contacts; it helps auth the gmail account.

we are setting the cookie by calling a function in a script tag in an html file:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    gapi.load('client:auth2', function () {
      window.gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: "%REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY%",
        clientId: "%REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID%",
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
        discoveryDocs: ['https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1'],
      })
    });
  </script>
```

is there a way to set this cookie (on our end) as secure so it must use an https connection?

Other vendors I have been able to get in touch with and they either tell me it isn't advisable/ possible or they will help me set it to secure.
Either would be acceptable, but with so many products google offers I haven't been able to find the right team, and the teams I have reached don't know who to direct me to. Hoping someone out there knows a documentable reason why it shouldn't be done, or can help me change it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write third-party cookies (i.e. where the cookie is on the domain of the third party) requires that the cookies be sent in the headers of a download from that third party, and not written by JS code.

(from this post [Can a 3rd party js script write cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747379/can-a-3rd-party-js-script-write-cookies) )

without the help of someone on the google side I don't believe this is possible